# How can I get the number of times a substring appears in a text

Tags: ruby

I want to get the number of occurrences of a substring in a text.

```
fullText = 'aa_bb_cc_dd_eeeee_ff'
substr   = 'ee'
```

I want to count how many times `ee` matches `aa_bb_cc_dd_eeeee_ff`, and the result should be `4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'aa_bb_cc_dd_eeeee_ff'.scan(/(?=ee)/).length
# => 4
```

Answer (score 0):

@sawa's solution is more efficient (and general) but if you want to do it without regexes, here's another way:

```
'aa_bb_cc_dd_eeeee_ff'.chars.each_cons(2).inject(0) { |c, (i,j)| 
    c+=1 if (i == 'e' && i == j); c 
 }
```